# Hoisting of let variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, hoisting

I defined the following function:

```
const func = ()=>{
  let a =  new Array(2).fill().map(i => new Array(2).fill(1));
  console.log(`%o`,a);
  a[0][0]++;
  return a;
}
```

When I implement `func()` in DevTools, the result is this:

```
(2) [Array(2), Array(2)]
0: (2) [2, 1]
1: (2) [1, 1]
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)


(2) [Array(2), Array(2)]
0: (2) [2, 1]
1: (2) [1, 1]
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I want the first one of

```
console.log(`%o`,a);
```

to be

```
[[1,1],[1,1]]
```

but the result was unexpected.

Why does this happen? Is this an example of `hoisting`?

Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: No, it's not hoisting. You can get around it with e.g. `console.log(JSON.stringify(a))`.

Comment: "Is this an example of hoisting?" — No, it is an example of mutating objects and asynchronicity.